# why doesn't my if/else statement match when the output of both is the same?

Tags: java, list, if-statement, arraylist, return-value

```
        List6 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List6.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@name='authorName']")).getAttribute("value"));
        System.out.println("List6 : " +List6);
        System.out.println("List1 : " +List1.get(u));
        if (List1.get(u).equals(List6)){
            System.out.println("author name checked!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("wrong author name!");
        }
```

why does it always return me with the else statement? i printed list 6 and 1 both give me the same return

this is the result

```
List6 : [alan]
List1 : alan
wrong author name!
```

my list 1 array

```
[alan, ben, chris, dawn, eva, fann, grace, helen, ian, jag, ken, lyn, stephen]
for (int u = 0; u < List1.size(); u++) {
            System.out.println(List1.get(u));
```

Comment: Because `[alan]` and `alan` are not equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `equals()` method on the `String` class is a character by character comparison of the contents of two strings.

Just before you make this comparison, you're printing out the strings, and anyone can quite easily see they're very different.  The reason you're entering the `else` part of the `if else` block is because `if (List1.get(u).equals(List6))` is always evaluating false.

`[alan]` and `alan` are not equivalent strings and when compared using `.equals()`, they will return `false`.

Comment: ohh okay now i see.. is there any way which i could resolve this?

Comment: There's nothing to resolve... the `equals()` method is working as intended.  If you mean you want to take the brackets off, then you should compare `List1.get(u)` to an individual element in `List6` rather than to the whole list (which will represent the list as comma separated and enclosed in square brackets).

Comment: so i should just compare my whole list 1 to list 6 iszit? oh okay got it! understand now! thank you!

Comment: No... in this context, you should compare an individual element of list 1 to an individual element of list 6.  `List1.get(u).equals(List6.get(0))`

Comment: `[alan]` isn't a String at all.  It's an ArrayList containing a String.  When formatted for printing (via the implicit `toString()` call) it displays like that.

Answer (score 0):

List1.get(u) is a String. 
List6 is a ArrayList. 
a String will never equal a ArrayList

Maybe you need change your code as below:

```
if (List1.get(u).equals(List6.get(0))){
        System.out.println("author name checked!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("wrong author name!");
    }
```